# Python - Capturing variables that don't exist

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm extracting data from one page and then sending it to a csv with `writerow`.

```
writerow([mystat,mystat1,mystat2...etc])
```

The issue I have is since I have so many variables (baseball stats) sometimes these numbers may not exist and I'm stuck with a:

```
"local variable 'mystat' referenced before assignment"
```

Is there a simple way of saying that if the variable does not exist, just set it to 0?

Comment: Could you post what the `page` that you're referencing looks like? It will help to see you data source and then I gather that your sending it to a csv.

Comment: No.  If the variable doesn't exist then your code is incorrect.  Post the code you have for retrieving the data.  That is where you should fill in a suitable placeholder value when applicable.

Comment: You should be using a dictionary, not a bunch of variables.  `for stat in list_of_stats: final_dict[stat] = page_lookup(stat) or 0` (or whatever)

Comment: Then it's easy to use a `csv.DictWriter` to write the rows.

Comment: @AdamSmith coming from engineering into programming, learning that you can use `or` like that in a dictionary is a crazy and welcome revelation, thanks! :) For OP, if you have missing data, you should assign it a value that can be removed from analysis e.g. empty strings or something else identifiable. Setting missing data to zero will skew all your stats if you plan to go forwards with some analysis.

Comment: @roganjosh it's just how Python deals with conditionals. Any chain of `or`s will evaluate to the last expression that resolves the boolean. e.g. if `page_lookup` gives a truthy value, `True or ...` is `True`, we don't care about the rest, so it evaluates as `page_lookup(...)`. If it gives a falsey value, we need to check the next in the chain, which is `0` (which is falsey in Python). Since there's nothing AFTER the zero, we can resolve to `False`, giving the `0` there as the terminating expression.

Comment: @AdamSmith Thank you for the explanation. I had the component parts in my head but, honestly, would never have made the connection that I could assign a value to the variable outside of a function until I saw that. You think you have the basics ironed out and then see something like that :)

Comment: @roganjosh ah yeah, that's just variable scoping in Python. Note, however, that I WOULDN'T do that. Much better to create the variable inside the function and return it if you need it afterwards. In this case it looks like this should be a `write_from_page` function or something like that

Comment: @AdamSmith Absolutely; it's one of those where I think it might have niche applications that may/may not be applicable to this question as the best approach. I have derailed this a bit in the discussion, I'm just appreciative that you demonstrated a completely different paradigm was possible outside of what I have learned (connecting the dots takes time and I don't believe I have seen that before in any code) so thank you again. I have a feeling it will come in useful somewhere!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals):

```
if 'var' not in locals():
    var = 0
```